# Which keywords did I missed on the following tables?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, dml

**My problem:** I get the same error on the tables: *Tasks*,  *TimeSheet*, *TimeSheetHour*.

I still don't have any idea on what keywords did I missed.

Here is the error I got in *Tasks* table: (same with other tables)
[image]

May I know which keywords did I missed on the following tables?

```
-- what keywords did I missed here?
CREATE TABLE Tasks(
    IdTask  NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,                  
    IdProject   NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,       
    Task_Name   VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,    
    Task_Description    VARCHAR2(100),
    StartDate   DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL,
    CreatedAt VARCHAR2(50),
    UpdatedAt VARCHAR2(50),
    Enabled CHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT IdTask_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdTask),
    CONSTRAINT IdProject_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdProject) REFERENCE Project_T(IdProject)
);
 

-- what keywords did I missed here?
CREATE TABLE TimeSheet(
    IdTimeSheet NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    IdUser NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    IdProject NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    TimeSheet_Name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    TimeSheet_Description VARCHAR2(200),
    CreatedAt VARCHAR2(50),
    UpdatedAt VARCHAR2(50),
    Enabled CHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT IdTimeSheet_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdTimeSheet),
    CONSTRAINT IdProject_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdProject) REFERENCE Project_T(IdProject),
    CONSTRAINT IdUser_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdUser) REFERENCE User_T(IdUser)
);


-- what keywords did I missed here?
CREATE TABLE TimeSheetHour(
    IdTimeSheetHour NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    IdTimeSheet NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    IdUser  NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    IdTimeCategory  NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    IdTask  NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    Quantity NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL,
    TimeSheetHour_Description VARCHAR2(200),
    CONSTRAINT IdTimeSheetHour_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdTimeSheetHour),
    CONSTRAINT IdTimeSheet_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdTimeSheet) REFERENCE (TimeSheet),
    CONSTRAINT IdUser_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdUser) REFERENCE (User_T),
    CONSTRAINT IdTimeCategory_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdTimeCategory) REFERENCE (TimeCategory),
    CONSTRAINT IdTask_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdTask) REFERENCE Tasks(IdTask)
);
```

Comment: REFERENCE**S**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't notice it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword is `REFERENCES` not `REFERENCE`.

Then you have constraints with duplicate names `IdProject_FK`.

Then you have foreign key constraints where you do not specify the table being referenced.

I.e.:

```sql
CONSTRAINT IdTimeSheet_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdTimeSheet) REFERENCE (TimeSheet)
```

Should be:

```sql
CONSTRAINT IdTimeSheet_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdTimeSheet) REFERENCES TimeSheet(IdTimeSheet)
```

or, without the braces and the explicit column name:

```sql
CONSTRAINT IdTimeSheet_FK FOREIGN KEY (IdTimeSheet) REFERENCES TimeSheet
```